# Так можно сказать?

Tags: словосочетания

"Рекомендация нас как профессионалов" так можно сказать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так: ***рекомендация нас как хороших специалистов.***

**Пояснение**

Обоснование по словарю. Слово ***профессионал*** имеет два значения, но подходит только одно.

**РЕКОМЕНДАЦИЯ**, -и; ж. [лат. recommendatio]. 1. к **Рекомендовать**. Пошёл на выставку по вашей рекомендации и не жалею.

**РЕКОМЕНДОВАТЬ,** св. и нсв. [от лат. recommendare]. 1. (св. также отрекомендовать и порекомендовать). кого-что. Дать - давать рекомендацию. Р. кого-л. с самой лучшей стороны. **Р. кого-л. КАК хорошего специалиста.**

**ПРОФЕССИОНАЛ**, -а; м. Тот, кто сделал какое-л. занятие, деятельность своей профессией. Охотник-профессионал. Товарищеская встреча хоккеистов-профессионалов. Садоводы профессионалы и любители. // Хороший специалист.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза с существительным «рекомендация» выглядит неуклюже. Классики предпочитали в подобных конструкциях глагольную форму.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
Посторонним людям рекомендовала нас как своих бедных родственниц, вдовицу и сироту беспомощных, которых она из милости, ради любви христианской, у себя приютила. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Бедные люди (1846)]
Заговорили и о литературе: мать и дочь рекомендовали Александра как писателя. [И. А. Гончаров. Обыкновенная история (1847)]
Боб рекомендовал вас как весьма опытного чиновника, знающего все ходы-выходы. [Анатолий Салуцкий. Немой набат // «Москва», 2019]

У глагола «рекомендовать»  имеются синонимы: характеризовать, квалифицировать, представлять, презентовать, которые (на мой взгляд) могут точнее передать смысл исходной фразы. Сравните, например: «характеризует нас как профессионалов».

Что, в общем-то, характеризует нас как существ изначально консервативных, не жадных, очевидно не склонных к экспансии и, по большому счету, небезнадежных. [Андрей Геласимов. Дом на Озерной (2009)]

Comment: А профессионалов оставляете?  Ваш окончательный вариант: "рекомендовать нас как профессионалов"?

Comment: Именно так. Словарное определение «тот, кто сделал какое-либо занятие, деятельность своей профессией» буквально означает, что этот человек 1) «профессионально пригоден», что подтверждается справками и/или записью в трудовой книжке и 2) его устраивает уровень заработков, обеспечиваемый работой по этой специальности (в этой профессии), а так же перспективы личного роста.

Comment: Очевидно, что это значение слова «профессионал» к обсуждаемому вопросу отношения не имеет. Однако второе значение «хороший специалист, знаток» подходит как нельзя кстати.
[Евдок666] Жаль, что сейчас нет Труса, Балбеса и Бывалого — настоящих комиков, настоящих актёров, профессионалов своего дела… [Форум: Операция «Ы» (2007-2011)]
Я убедился, что вы профессионал высокого класса. [Виктор Пронин. Банда 8 (2005)]

Comment: Вот именно что так. Говорится, скорее всего, о хорошем специалисте, а понять можно иначе (по отношению к профессии). Поэтому речь была именно об этом слове, а не глаголе/существительном. Оно-то как раз здесь и выглядит неподходящим.

Comment: Словосочетание «как профессионалов», на мой взгляд, исключает возможность двойного толкования. Речь идет о классных специалистах и знатоках своего дела, но ни в коем случае не о людях, которые «звезд с неба не хватают», а просто профессионально пригодны.

Comment: Это вы так  понимаете значение предложения. Да, верно, здесь речь идет о классных специалистах. Но вы забываете о СТИЛИСТИКЕ.  Возможность двойного истолкования в любом случае является стилистической погрешностью и напрягает наш слух. Поэтому надо заменить профессионалов на специалистов.

Answer (score 0):

Выйти из неловкой ситуации поможет предложный падеж:

> Первым словом которого была рекомендация о себе: «Порт-Артурский
> герой»...

*Рекомендация о нас как профессионалах.*

Comment: Shampar, в словарях нет предложного управления.

Comment: Не сочтите за труд формулировать понятно. Поясню, тем не менее: в контексте примера из вопроса РЕКОМЕНДАЦИЯ есть положительный ОТЗЫВ (кого-то о ком-то). Не может быть запрета для предложного управления.

Comment: При многозначности слова у каждого значения(если необходимо) приводится управление для каждого значения отдельно. В словаре нет такого управления. Следовательно, такое правление не является корректным.

Comment: Примеры в НКРЯ: «...рекомендация о создании в регионе Международного центра; ...рекомендация о вводе единого электронного билета; ...рекомендация о переносе сроков референдума в Чечне». Словарь составляется людьми, статистически фиксирующими явление. Надо просто подождать.